# Can't write the file when I'm trying to download it with my app

Tags: android

I made an Async task in order to make the download. It should work but my problem is really at the beginning of the download process, when I'm trying to create the new downloaded file.
This is my code:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/yLCSdue.png");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if(connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            Log.i("loc", "" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getRootDirectory()+ "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/image.jpg");
            Log.i("download", "downloading");
```

And when I run it I get the exception:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/Download/image.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

I tried different directions like:

```
                output = new FileOutputStream("image.jpg");
```

and I got this exception:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: image.jpg (Read-only file system)
```

I tried to use:

```
                output = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/image.jpg");
```

and got:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/image.jpg (Permission denied)
```

I don't know what to do so I can create the file and write to it..
I didn't find any permission in the manifest that can help me with this.. I want to write to internal storage to the "Downloads" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this permission before starting Application in Manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Then your path may be not correct... try with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: on new devices you have to grant the permission manually: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: you were right, I had to manually request permission because my emulator is running android 7.0. It worked!